# angular built-in directive is not working after custom checkbox directive (with isolate scope) added

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a custom checkbox directive in Angular, and I have managed to do so. but the problem is that the build-in `ng-click` is not called. if the custom directive is removed, the `ng-click` works well. I guess it is something to do with Scope, which I am still lacking knowledge to figure out. can anybody help me please.

the code is here http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/UzM2c/2/.

```
<div ng-app="components">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="p.checked" />
         <div checkbox="p.checked" ng-click="test()">test</div>
         {{p.checked}}
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
function MainCtrl($scope){ 
    $scope.p = {checked: false,  name:'test'};
    $scope.$watch('p', function(){

    }, true);

    $scope.test = function(){
        alert('test');
    }
}

angular.module('components', []).
directive('checkbox', function () {
return {
    link : function (scope, ele, attr){
        ele.bind('click', function(){
            ele.toggleClass('active');
            scope.$apply(function(){
                scope.value = ele.hasClass('active');
            });
        });

        scope.$watch('value', function(newv, oldv){
            newv ? ele.addClass('active') : ele.removeClass('active');
        });
    },
    scope : {
        value: '=checkbox'
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have a directive with an isolated scope try this:

```
<div checkbox="p.checked" ng-click="$parent.test()">test</div>
```

That will work.
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 8):

Although @Yahya's answer will work, instead of using `$parent`, which can break if your HTML structure changes (i.e., HTML changes can change how scopes are inherited), you should instead specify in an HTML attribute which method/callback you want your directive to call when the element is clicked:

```
<div checkbox="p.checked" cb="test()">test</div>
```

Then in your directive:

```
ele.bind('click', function(){
   ele.toggleClass('active');
   scope.cb();               // calls test()
   scope.$apply(function(){
     scope.value = ele.hasClass('active');
   });
});
...        
scope : {
   value: '=checkbox',
   cb: '&',
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/yKWpb/)

Comment: this is indeed a better approach. I was actually trying this approach, but could not get it to work because I did not call the test(), anyway votes up since I have accepted an answer. thanks for sharing.

Comment: this should be the correct answer. Basically anytime Mark responds to something, he's right. Don't argue, just agree and move on. :)